# Cannot find correct CSS in Sotefront for Mini CART Background Colour

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to change all the elements in the mini cart element to the same background colour for [www.wizardmodels.ltd][1] to #800000

Current it is a mixed with #710000

However, I cannot find the right CSS to change all the elements.

E.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart, .main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-
menu, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children {
background-color: #800000;
}
}
```

OR

```
.widget .woocommerce .widget_shopping_cart {
background-color: #800000 !important;
}
```

OR BOTH

Always leave the bottom portion (with Sub-total) in the desired #80000 AND the middle portion in the mysterious #710000.

I can change it in the Google console. Looking at the page source the colour appears in the code:

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart,
.main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu,
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children {
background-color: #710000;
}
```

Changing that does not work either.

Any ideas, please?

ps, no need to buy anything :)

---

PART 2

I have added a screen shot. The code that provides this is

```
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart p {
background-color: #800000 !important;
}

.widget_shopping_cart .buttons, .widget_shopping_cart .total {
background-color: #800000 !important;
}
```

Have got no further. Also clearing cache. The work is done on a local server.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the this mini cart you are referring to?  It's a little confusing to understand what exactly you need changed.

Comment: Yes, if you go to http://www.wizardmodels.ltd/ and add an item then hover over the cart.

Answer (score 0):

**TOP PART**

```
li.woocommerce-mini-cart-item.mini_cart_item {
    background-color: #800000 !important;
}
```

**BOTTOM PART**

```
header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .buttons, .site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .total {
    background-color: #710000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I take it that you want the entire drop-down "mini-cart" background color to be the same (#800000)?  If so you just need to change add this.

```
.widget_shopping_cart p.total {
    background: #800000;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Let me know if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Droid and BrandonElder. The 'Bottom Part' of Droid's answer worked. See edited Question

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the hex codes of the two colours in the wpdb. And found the following in options. I then edited out the two colours I did not want. The code below works. I suspect the options were overriding the suggested CSS (above)?

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
            .secondary-navigation ul.menu a:hover {
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .secondary-navigation ul.menu a {
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart,
            .main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu,
            .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul.children {
                background-color: #800000;
            }

            .site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .buttons,
            .site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart .total {
                background-color: #800000;
            }

            .site-header {
                border-bottom-color: #800000;
            }
```

I can only assume that these crept in somewhere during the build, they are colours I would have tried. I have used a 3rd part plugin which suggested it could provide easy modification of the theme. Was this the culprit, even after uninistalling!